# Django How to download existing file?

Tags: python, django, view, download

in my Django 'views, I create a pdf file and I want to download it.
The file exist (path: /app/data/4.pdf) and i launch this command:

```
def download_line(request):
    if not request.is_ajax() and not request.method == 'GET':
        raise Http404

    try:
        fs =FileSystemStorage('/app/data')
        with fs.open('4.pdf') as pdf:
            response =HttpResponse(pdf,content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition']='attachment; filename="4.pdf"'


    except Exception as e:
        logger.warning("Download Line | Erreur : " + e.message)


    return response
```

But the download doesn't start and no error. Have you got a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need to call the `read()` method on the pdf (File) object. i.e. `HttpResponse(pdf.read(), cont…`

Comment: No it doessn't work, i should download in javascript side?

Comment: It seems that you want to serve a file using Ajax, it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: Ok , i can't download  file from the server using Ajax, How can i do this in javascript side?

Comment: Just use a `<a href=...>` to download. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31040851/1977847

Answer (score 2):

I use [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) to serve file download, when the file already exists. FileResponse has been around since Django 1.7.4.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.http import FileResponse

def download_line(request):
    fs = FileSystemStorage('/absolute/folder/name')
    FileResponse(fs.open('filename.pdf', 'rb'), content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename.pdf"'
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download existing file in your app by a link and static, like this

```
<a href="{% static 'questions/import_files/import_questions.xlsx' %}" download>Excel Format File </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I use this lines to download files

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

import os

def download(request, file_path):
    """
    e.g.: file_path = '/tmp/file.pdf'
    """
    try:
        wrapper = FileWrapper(open(file_path, 'rb'))
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        return None
```

Comment: It doesn't works, error "The view paquet.views.download didn't return an HttpResponse Object. It returned None instead", pb seems to be when wrapper

Comment: This Error happens when the `file_path` is incorrect

Comment: @smiss According to the example, the function expects a file in `C:\tmp\file.pdf` (Windows) or `/tmp/file.pdf` (Linux)

Answer (score -2):

```
def sample_download_client_excel(request):
    """
    e.g.: file_path = '/tmp/file.pdf'
    """
    try:
        obj = SampleFile.objects.all().first()
        file_path = obj.file_name.url.strip('/') 
        wrapper = FileWrapper(open(file_path, 'rb'))
        response = HttpResponse(
            wrapper, 
            content_type='application/force-download'
        )
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        return None
```